# Dict comprehension: Dict of Pivot Tables from Dict of Dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pivot, dictionary-comprehension

I've used a dictionary comprehension to end up with a dictionary of tables/dataframes:

```
tables = {group: table for group, table in tmp.groupby('Group')}
```

Each table has data in this format:

```
name  area  date  value
a      11   3/1/22  1 
b      22   4/1/22  2
```

I would like to make a pivot table out of each dataframe/table in the dictionary like so:

```
pd.pivot_table(table/df name here, index=['name','area'], columns='Date', values='Value')
```

Am I able to do this working on the same dictionary, with a comprehension?  If no, whats the best way to cycle through the items in `tables` and run the pivot code on each item?

Comment: you can make a new dict with pivoted table and do something like `[new_dict[item[0]] = pd.pivot_table(item[1], other args) for item in tables.item() ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Nested for loops to create muliple pivot table based on 2 level multiindex in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61413591/nested-for-loops-to-create-muliple-pivot-table-based-on-2-level-multiindex-in-pa) there is a solution to a similar problem that involves dictionary comprehension with data frames.

Using that link and https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/ I was able to piecemeal something together for myself:

```
index = ['Date']
dfpivot = {k: v.pivot(index=index,columns='A',values='B').reset_index() for k,v in dfdict.items()}
```

This iterates through a dictionary of data frames `dfdict`. Creating a pivot table for each data frame (based on date) in the dictionary and storing it to a new dictionary of pivoted data frames `dfpivot`. Hopefully this will set you up on the right track. I think in your case you would just need to adjust the pivot part of the code above implementing what is here https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html.